# How to Lazy Load the @Named Bean

Tags: spring, jsf, cdi

I have a **SessionScoped** **Named** Bean as follows:

```
@Named("userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
  .....
   @PostConstruct
      public void init()
       {
            ...call some methods to fetch some data
       }
```

Now the problem is, while deploying the application, **init()** will be called, and through-out the session it will not be called again.
My requirement is to make the **init()** call only when the bean is required to be initialized.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Named("userBean")
@SessionScoped
@Lazy
public class UserBean implements Serializable
```

And wherever you have `@Autowired UserBean`

make it

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
UserBean userbean;
```